# PDO couldn't find driver

Tags: php

I tried executing php artisan migrate. I got this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t
able_schema = dreametrytrellov1 and table_name = migrations)

[PDOException]
could not find driver
```

I'm using php 5.6.31

Comment: you have `pdo-mysql` extension turned on, in you `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes i have removed the comment on extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: That only works if you have the actual file on your server...

Comment: I have the file on my server

Comment: Have you restarted you server to apply changes?